# Adding a Value to Collection Items

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I want to load data from many files. Each file is named with a date and I need to inject this date to each of the fetched Entries of my file.
I know I could do this with an foreach - loop before inserting the data into the collection, but I think there should be a better solution.

Content of one file

```json
[{"price":"95,34","isin":"FR0000120073"},{"price":"113,475","isin":"CA13645T1003"}]
```

The Code I use to move the data into a collection.

```php
$collection= collect(json_decode(File::get($file)));
```

I tried for example the "map" method, however I don't know how to pass an additional variable to the anonymous function.

The content of my collection should look like this:

```json
[{"price":"95,34","isin":"FR0000120073","date":"2016-06-23"},{"price":"113,475","isin":"CA13645T1003","date":"2016-06-23"}]
```

Is there any simple solution using the collections or do I have to use a foreach-loop?

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help

```
$collection = collect(json_decode(File::get($file)));

$collection = $collection->each(function ($item, $key) {
    //First iteration of $item will be {"price":"95,34","isin":"FR0000120073"}
    $item->date = "2016-06-23"; //Insert key, value pair to the collection
  });
```

Comment: I have to dynamically set the date, so I have to pass a variable to this function.

Comment: I had an idea and used a global variable. Nevertheless this is just a workaround not a real solution.